# Showing a section on a page when loaded, but still able to be hidden when clicked?

Tags: html, css

I'm here regarding a question about having a section already loaded in when the page starts, but to still be able to hide it later on. I've hidden it from the start with example of the code below:

```
section {
    display: none;
  }
```

and I re-enable it with :target, like so:

```
section:target {
    display: block;

    }
```

To change the sections and what is shown, I have ids set for letters *a* through *c*, and to enable them with the target I use href:

```
<div id="sidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="#a">About</a>
  <a href="#b">Works</a>
  <a href="#c">Contact</a>
</div>
```

Is it possible to have section *a* loaded, but still be able to clicked off of, and transitioned into another id / section?

**An example of a section within my code.**

```html
  <section class="fade-in" id="a">
      <h1>
        Hey, welcome to my site!
      </h1>
      <p class=p3>Come take a look to everything!</p>

    </section>
```

If you need more code / an idea of what I am trying to express, please let me know.
Thank you.

Comment: do you wish to use javascript?

Comment: Yes, I'm willing to do any method to get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't styled it. Don't mind.

```js
let sidenav = document.querySelector('#sidenav')
let def = document.querySelector('#a')
sidenav.addEventListener('click', () => {
  def.classList.remove('default')
})
```

```css
.default {
  display: block !important;
}

section {
  display: none;
}

section:target {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="sidenav" class="sidenav">
    <a href="#a">About</a>
    <a href="#b">Works</a>
    <a href="#c">Contact</a>
  </div>
  <section class="fade-in default" id="a">
    <h1>
      Hey, welcome to my site!
    </h1>
    <p class=p3>Come take a look to everything!</p>

  </section>
  <section class="fade-in" id="b">
    <h1>
      this is another something
    </h1>
    <p class=p3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>

  </section>
  <section class="fade-in" id="c">
    <h1>
      Another sample stuff
    </h1>
    <p class=p3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>

  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

**Hope this Helps**

Comment if any doubt

Comment: After attempting to plug in code into my own, I run into a few issues, and the section id a doesn't go away after I click on something else. Am I doing something wrong? I made a fiddle, and added the other code that I did not have in my example. Thank you again though. https://jsfiddle.net/exdkfbo9/1/

Comment: Listen.. **ALWAYS** add javascript at the end of the HTML. Just move the _script_ to the bottom of the `<body>` tag just above `</body>`

Comment: Done deal, also this was the solution so thank you! I just realized that I had accidently renamed the 'default' to something else, which caused issues. Just now that if you refresh the page while having #c selected for example, it will load #a again.

Comment: Yes you have to make one of them the default, so that every time a person visits your page it shows it first. And reloading the page is same as revisiting it. BTW pls accept my answer

Answer (score 1):

**I hope, This code may solve your problem.**

```css
:root {
  --headerfont: #e13470;
  --mainfont: #ffffff;
  --bgcolor: #0c0b10;
  --sidenav: #13111b;
  --selectioncolor: #1f1b2a;
  --selectioncolorbar: #1f1b2a;
  --selectorfont: #e13470;
}

body {
  background-color: var(--bgcolor);
  font-family: "Iosevka", Georgia, sans-serif;
  width: calc(100% - 6em);
}

div.content {
  padding: 0.3rem 0.9rem;
}

h1 {
  color: var(--headerfont);
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-style: oblique;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding-top: 4rem;
  padding-left: 5rem;
  padding-right: 18rem;
}

h2 {
  color: var(--headerfont);
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-style: oblique;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding-top: 2rem;
  padding-left: 5rem;
  padding-right: 18rem;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 32px;
  color: var(--headerfont);
  font-weight: 500;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: var(--mainfont);
  outline: none;
  padding-left: 5rem;
  padding-right: 18rem;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

.p2 {
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  font-weight: 200;
  position: relative;
  font-style: oblique;
  color: var(--mainfont);
  outline: none;
  line-height: 1.4;
  padding-left: 5rem;
  padding-right: 18rem;
}

.p3 {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  font-weight: 200;
  position: relative;
  font-style: oblique;
  color: var(--mainfont);
  outline: none;
  line-height: 1.4;
  padding-left: 5rem;
  padding-right: 18rem;
}

.default {
  display: block !important;
}

section {
  display: none;
}

section:target {
  display: block;
}

.medialist {
  text-underline-position: under;
  outline: none;
}

.fade-in {
  animation: fadein 2s;
  -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox */
  -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-animation: fadein 2s; /* Opera */
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  flex-basis: 33%;
}
ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.fade-in {
  height: 300px;
  background: #dddddd;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1rem;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #333333;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  z-index: 0;
}

#main section.fade-in:first-child {
  z-index: 1;
}

section.fade-in:target {
  display: flex;
  z-index: 2;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

a {
  transition: ease 0.3s, background-color 0.3s;
  font-weight: 200;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--mainfont);
  outline: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: var(--selectorfont);
  outline: none;
  background-color: var(--selectioncolor);
}

/* The side navigation menu */
.sidenav {
  height: 100%; /* 100% Full-height */
  width: 16rem;
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Stay on top */
  top: 0; /* Stay at the top */
  right: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: var(--sidenav);
  overflow-x: hidden; /* Disable horizontal scroll */
  padding-top: 17rem;
  outline: none;
}

/* The navigation menu links */
.sidenav a {
  padding: 1.7rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: var(--headerfont);
  display: block;
  transition: width 0.4s;
  outline: none;
  font-weight: 200;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  background-color: var(--selectioncolorbar);
  transition: ease 0.4s;
}

.sidenav a::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 1px;
  transition: width 0.4s, background-color 0.4s;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  background-color: var(--selectioncolorbar);
}
/* When you mouse over the navigation links, change their color */
.sidenav a:hover::after {
  background-color: var(--headerfont);
  width: 70%;
  outline: none;
  transition: width 0.4s;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .sidenav {
    width: 97.9vw;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
  }

  .sidenav a::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 1px;
    transition: width 0.4s, background-color 0.4s;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
  }
  /* When you mouse over the navigation links, change their color */
  .sidenav a:hover::after {
    background-color: var(--fadinginto);
    width: 0%;
  }

  .sidenav a {
    float: left;
  }
  div.content {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .sidenav a {
    text-align: center;
    float: none;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="blah.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#a">A</a></li>
    <li><a href="#b">B</a></li>
    <li><a href="#c">C</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="main">
  <section class="fade-in" id="a">
      <h1>
        Hey, welcome to my site A!
      </h1>
      <p class=p3>Come take a look to everything!</p>

    </section>
  <section class="fade-in" id="b">
      <h1>
        Hey, welcome to my site B!
      </h1>
      <p class=p3>Come take a look to everything!</p>

    </section>
  <section class="fade-in" id="c">
      <h1>
        Hey, welcome to my site C!
      </h1>
      <p class=p3>Come take a look to everything!</p>

    </section>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sadly, it wasn't able to fix my issue, and as said to the other user, if you wish to see the code with my code, https://jsfiddle.net/f0rvdxun/ Thank you again though.

Comment: @asc_00 Ohhh, you can try this link. May be it will work for you. https://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/04/12/animated-content-tabs-with-css3/